# REGEX for stripping http://, https:// and www from website

Tags: regular-expressions

For a custom field "Domain," I want to strip extraneous elements like those in the subject line, which often end up in the field through web-to-lead. Can anyone suggest a REGEX formula for stripping those elements?

Comment: There are 83,000 questions about regular expressions here http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info; you may find the answer there and if you don't asking there will probably get you an answer quicker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** I think I've misinterpreted your requirements for scrubbing fields that shouldn't contain URLs. Still, I'll leave this here as my preferred method for parsing the elements of a URL.

---

Personally, I'd skip the Regex and utilise the built in [System.URL class](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_CSH.htm#apex_methods_system_url.htm).

```
string urlAsString = 'http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/30408/regex-for-stripping-http-https-and-www-from-website';
System.Url parsedUrl = new System.Url(urlAsString);
System.debug(parsedUrl.getHost());
System.debug(parsedUrl.getPath());
```

Outputs:

> salesforce.stackexchange.com
>   /questions/30408/regex-for-stripping-http-https-and-www-from-website

You may also need the Port and Query depending on your requirements.

Comment: Thank you! Very useful to get this steer away from REGEX and toward the system class.